# keytool -list shows different aliases for p12 keystore, depending on whether you provide the password

Tags: alias, keytool, private-key, pkcs#12

*Really* weird behaviour on a particular p12 file.

If I run

```
keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_debug_keystore.p12 -storepass debug
keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_debug_keystore.p12 -storepass debug
```

I get,

```
Alias name: 1
Creation date: Aug 17, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=sixminute, OU=, O=, C=IE
Issuer: CN=sixminute, OU=, O=, C=IE
Serial number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Valid from: Wed Nov 07 13:34:40 GMT 2012 until: Sun Nov 08 13:34:40 GMT 2037
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

and

```
Your keystore contains 1 entry

1, Aug 17, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However, if I *don't* provide the password in the commands,

```
keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_debug_keystore.p12
keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_debug_keystore.p12
```

the output is different,

```
Alias name: 2
Creation date: Aug 17, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=sixminute, OU=, O=, C=IE
Issuer: CN=sixminute, OU=, O=, C=IE
Serial number: 2d36623161363935353a31336165303361636133313a2d38303030
Valid from: Wed Nov 07 13:34:40 GMT 2012 until: Sun Nov 08 13:34:40 GMT 2037
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

and

```
Your keystore contains 1 entry

2, Aug 17, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Specifically a different alias for the same key (the MD5 and SHA1 are still the same for the keys).

Any idea at all why this would be the case?

Answer (score 12):

Aliases are not quite a PKCS 12 concept.  There is a Friendly Name attribute but it is very optional.  So I would guess that Java is just making up the Alias names it reports.  No idea why it would be different though, as the safe bag order should be the same.